# react-mapbox-gl Features don't work with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to use [react-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl) with [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/). Just trying to get the demo working, a map with a single Feature...

If I try the recommended [boilerplate](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl-debug) (based on [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/)) for debugging purposes, it works just fine:

[image: mapbox-working-with-create-react-app]

However when I go for a boilerplate with NextJS, the map renders with no Feature.

**pages/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Layer, Feature } from 'react-mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';

const Map = dynamic(() => import('../lib/mapbox'), {
    ssr: false
});

function HomePage() {
    return (
    <Map
        center={[-104.989713, 39.730212]}
        style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        containerStyle={{
            height: '100vh',
            width: '100vw'
        }}
    >
        <Layer type="circle" id="marker" paint={{
            'circle-radius': 50,
            'circle-color': '#E54E52',
            'circle-opacity': 1,
        }}>
            <Feature coordinates={[-104.995210, 39.754684]} />
        </Layer>
    </Map>);
}

export default HomePage;
```

**lib/mapbox.js**

```
import ReactMap from 'react-mapbox-gl';

export default ReactMap({
    accessToken: "pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFicmljOCIsImEiOiJjaWc5aTV1ZzUwMDJwdzJrb2w0dXRmc2d0In0.p6GGlfyV-WksaDV_KdN27A"
});
```

[image: mapbox-broken-nextjs]

I found [this closed thread](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/issues/146) on using *react-mapbox-gl* with NextJS. They explain how to use NextJS [Dynamic Imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import), however it seems like this does not fix the problem.

Comment: I found a solution of sorts, to use a different library!  [`react-map-gl`](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl) seems to work, having followed [this guide](https://github.com/leerob/next-mapbox-demo). So I've abandoned `react-mapbox-gl`. Oh well, I'll leave the question up in case anyone is interested in figuring out what is going on with this specific library and NextJS...

Comment: working with nextjs atm trying to get this to work. Did you ever revisit this to find a solution?

Comment: see my prior comment, I bailed on `react-mapbox-gl` and instead am happily using [`react-map-gl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-map-gl)